# Kendo UI kendoMaskedTextBox 24 Hour clock

Tags: regex, kendo-ui, kendo-maskedtextbox

I'm trying to create masked textbox, where you are able to type in maximum 24:00, but I can't make the regex dependent on each other. Now i'm able to type in ex. 25:00. If the first char is 2 I need only to be able to type in < 5. Can anyone help?

```
$(".hoursBox").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "12:34",
    rules: {
        "1": /[0-2]/,
        "2": /[0-9]/,
        "3": /[0-5]/,
        "4": /[0-9]/
   }
});
```

Comment: -I think- you would have to use
$(id).keydown(TwentyFourHoursOnly)

And within the function TwentyFourHoursOnly test for all the cases, using e,preventDefault() if it doesn't pass.

Comment: I've got the same problem but I'm going to cheat and use Asp Mvc validation instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below regex for this

```
((?!00)[0-1][0-9]|2[1-4]):[0-5][0-9]
```

***How it works***

1. the first digit should be any of `[0-1]`.
2. Second digit should be any thing from `[0-9]`.
3. But the first and second digits cannot be '00' and so we can use negative look-ahead to test this `(?!00)`.
4. The third character should be a colon ( `:` ).
5. The fourth character should be be any of `[0-5]`.
6. The fifth character should be any of `[0-9]`.

You can see the how it matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/jJ3wP6/1).

Comment: Thx, I can see the regex works perfect. But i can't get it to work with kendoMaskedTextBox. This does not work:
$(".hoursBox").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "00:00",
    rules: { "0": /((?!00)[0-1][0-9]|2[1-4]):[0-5][0-9]/ }
});

Comment: This won't work with kendoMaskedTextBox, the rule just says whats allowed within the single digit, not the whole box.

Answer (score 0):

I did this.

```
<kendo-maskedtextbox
              [includeLiterals]="true"
              [formControl]="formGroup.get('duration')"
              mask="000d12h34m"
              [rules]="rules"
              (keydown)="onKey(formGroup.get('duration'))"
            >
            </kendo-maskedtextbox>


 public rules = {
    '1': /[0-2]/,
    '2': /[0-9]/,
    '3': /[0-5]/,
    '4': /[0-9]/,
  };

  public onKey(fg: FormControl) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // check for hours > 23
      if (Number(fg.value?.split('d')[1].substring(0, 2)) > 23) {
        const value = fg.value.substring(0, 5) + ` ` + fg.value.substring(6);
        fg.setValue(value);
      }
    }, 200);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding a little details (i.e. how your code works or how did you solve a particular problem) when posting a snippet.